# How to update with a has many relationship

Tags: go, go-gorm

I use the gorm with the has many。
This is my model

```
type Pro struct {
    Model
    TaxRate              []TaxRate  `json:"taxRate" gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE;"`
}
```

```
type TaxRate struct {
    ID        uint
    Tax       float64
    ProjectID uint
}
```

but when I update the project, I found that the TaxRate just insert the record not update.
This is my update operation

```
result:=pRepo.db.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Updates(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the gorm documentation on has-many relationships (https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html) the automatic relation needs to be `structnameID`, so in your case ProID (the owner struct is called Pro and not Project). Either rename the struct or the reference or add `gorm:"foreignKey:ProjectID"` as tag:

```
type Pro struct {
    Model
    TaxRate []TaxRate `json:"taxRate" gorm:"foreignKey:ProjectID;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE;"`
}
```

Comment: thanks your reply. I have solved this problem. when I update the  Pro,i forget to send the TaxRateID. I found that in gorm doc.  If the TaxRateID is not send,it will insert,otherwise it update.